# Firefox not autostarting

Tags: firefox, autostart, ubuntu-minimal

I have Ubuntu **mini** installed with the **lubuntu core** option (used **Ubuntu 18.04-mini.iso**).

I don't have the rich Ubuntu interface.
In order to make Firefox start automatically, added a line containing

**@firefox**

to file

/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/**autostart**.

However, Firefox isn't starting.
Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### The cli way

**Method specific to LXDE/LXQT desktop** (simple)

---

```
ls ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu
```

if autostart does exist

```
echo 'firefox' >> ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

if autostart doesn't exist

`echo 'firefox' > ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

---

**Method according to the Desktop Application Autostart Specification** (also works in other desktop environments)

---

Try adding the firefox.desktop file to the ~/.config/autostart directory.

In my case:

```
cp ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

If it doesn't exist on your system, then create it:

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
```

then copy from /usr/share/applications

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

use preferred editor app(vi,nano)

```
edit `~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop`
```

search for `Exec=firefox %u`

change to `Exec=firefox`

save

logout/login to confirm

### GUI Method

Goto Menu > Preferences > Default Applications for LXSession

Click "Autostart" tab.

Under "Manual autostarted applications"

type `firefox` in the the textbox. Then click add.

exit then logout/login to confirm.

Comment: Thank you!
Firefox autostarts now, but tries to go to 
file:///home/<username>/%u, doesn't find it, and complains:
"Firefox can't find the file at /home/<username>/%u".
How to avoid that?

Comment: Why "Ugly"?  It is a common agreed method that works across desktops.

Comment: My Menu > Preferences doesn't have that option (mine is a Ubuntu Mini install).
Noted that ~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop was empty, but if I try to add a line
Exec=firefox [  paulo@ubuntu:~$ edit ~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop] I get [ Error: no write permission for file "/home/paulo/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop"]. Then issued [ sudo su] and tried to edit firefox.desktop with leafpad, but got some cryptic error messages.

Comment: Copied firefox.desktop as directed. Noted that its last line was "Exec=firefox -private-window"; changed it to "Exec=firefox". However, when autostarts, Firefox still tries to open "file:///home/paulo/%u" (paulo is my username).

Comment: that was the incorrect line. Find the line *`Exec=firefox %u`* . Change that to `Exec=firefox`

Comment: Sorry, my oversight - missed that other line. Everything working now. Many thanks for adding to my knowledge and for your kind patience.